# Downloads folder in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: 8.1

How do I see what's in the downloads folder? When I plug the phone into the computer I can view the contents of the downloads folder but when using the phone directly I can't find the download folder.

Comment: For downloaded PDFs, you are able to open the default Reader app or Adobe Reader and view the _recent_ documents.

Comment: @M.Mimpen yes, and file zip?

Comment: Not sure if you ar being ironic, but I only provided a quick tip _for downloaded pdfs_ - not an answer.

Comment: Looks like this will answer your question: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/414/where-do-downloaded-files-go and you could check out the app [File Explorer](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/file-explorer/8d87e9b9-6e03-4585-a947-339ff038dd3b)

Comment: I think you can only view the folders on SkyDrive using your phone directly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can view the contents of the downloads folder using **Files**, the official file management app for Windows Phone 8.1.

You can download the app [here](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=762e837f-461d-4847-8399-3526f54fc25e). For more information, see [this answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/3807/1401), or the [official announcement](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2014/05/30/introducing-files-a-file-management-app-for-windows-phone-8-1.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

The phone does not yet provide a native way to explore the shared memory locations. However they now allow in 8.1, apps to do so. [Aerize Explorer](http://aerize.com/windows/explorer/) ([direct](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=f18c01a2-716a-4b7e-8a26-43bbc18da986)) is an example of a third party application that already can view the contents of your downloads folder (and others) from the phone itself.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access folder contents directly from your phone. Every file in that folder can be accessed only by the apps that supports their format. Pictures in the gallery, Music from the music app, Pdfs from Adobe Reader etc etc.

Anything that gives you access to all content on a folder shared by many/all apps is a potential threat to the security of your content.