# File manager in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: 8.1

I've heard the rumour that a **file manager** (don't know if a third-party app) is coming with Windows Phone 8.1 that allows read/write, cut/copy/paste and rename of files stored in phone memory and on the SD card. Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no file manager app that comes with Windows Phone OS 8.1. However you can get such apps from the store such as [Aerize Explorer](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=f18c01a2-716a-4b7e-8a26-43bbc18da986) or [Pocket Explorer](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=ef636d74-3f80-4a2b-94c1-453777411d2a) (best of the many apps).

[This article](http://www.wpcentral.com/file-managers-windows-phone-81) might also help.

**Updated**

> **[Official File Manager for Windows Phone 8.1 due in May, here's what it looks like](http://www.wpcentral.com/official-file-manager-windows-phone-81)**
>   
> Source: [Windows Phone Central](http://www.wpcentral.com/)

Answer (score 13):

An official file manager called **[Files](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=762e837f-461d-4847-8399-3526f54fc25e)** is now available! It allows users to browse, search, manage and share files on their phone as well as SD card. Supported file operations include mass move/copy/rename/delete.

Some screenshots:

[image] [image] [image]

More information at the following links:

- [Introducing Files - a file management app for Windows Phone 8.1](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2014/05/30/introducing-files-a-file-management-app-for-windows-phone-8-1.aspx) (Windows Phone Blog)
- [Windows Phone 8.1 gets official file manager](http://www.wpcentral.com/windows-phone-81-gets-official-file-manager) (WPCentral)

Comment: Wow! I was so waiting for this! :D Thank you for sharing. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

in addition to those mentioned you can also try my new app [**FileEx**](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=d1e48e7a-eafe-469a-a7aa-6733cfdadaf9), it supports batch file operations like **copying and moving multiple folders and files** at the same time or renaming mutiple files at once.

I accept any feedback so send me any questions or issues :-) .

Comment: Yeah sure , But windows phone 8.1 update is not rolled out yet ....

Comment: I'm afraid no true file explorer can be built for Windows Phone 8, there are API limits...

Comment: Yes, i know. Windows phone 8.1 update will rolled out within one month , i think.