# Where are files downloaded from Gmail stored?

Tags: email, gmail, attachments

Where do the files downloaded from Gmail (which were received as attachments) go in the Files app? I am not able to locate them.

Comment: It's not the exact same scenario but maybe a duplicate of http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/414/where-do-downloaded-files-go

Comment: Pocket file explorer does good job in showing up all of them.But it is paid app. Only relevant apps scan the files and show you.

Answer (score 2):

Initially, they're in a temp folder. If you tap and hold, you'll be able to save somewhere directly.

If you want to save the a photo, open the individual attachment by tapping on it after the download is complete, then tap Save and it will get saved to your Saved Photos folder

If it is a document, it's a little funnier. You have to open the "Office" app and then select "email: opened attachments"

I haven't been able to find where PDFs go yet.