# Destination of various photos

Tags: 8.1

I have a Lumia 635 with Windows 8.1. Any time I download an emailed photo or receive a photo via WhatsApp, I can find all these photos in my "photos" on the phone, a feature I love. My wife has a Lumia 1020 with 8.1. Anytime she downloads an emailed photo to her phone or opens a photo in WhatsApp, the photos do *NOT* end up in her "photos" section. In fact, we have no idea where they go! We've searched the phone (not via computer) but to no avail. We want to show these photos to others but we re unable. Where can we find these photos?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your wife's Lumia 1020 doesn't store photos in the Photos section but either way there's an easy way to find them.

There's an app in the Store called [Files](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Files/9WZDNCRFJ3PL). It's made by Microsoft. This app gives you a detailed view on your files sortened by type (Documents, Music, Pictures etc). Via this app you can find any file according to its type. Download it and you'll find your file in no time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Photos downloaded via an Email client **will not be saved to phone** automatically. They will be stored in the app memory. So they cannot be viewed in photos section. To save a photo from the Mail app follow the instructions in a similar question found [here](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/8859/18061).

However if you are downloading a photo from an Email using a browser your photos will be saved in *SDcard->Downloads* as [said](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/12647/18061) by Nirav Madariya.

To answer your other questions photos saved from Whatsapp will be stored in *sdCard->Pictures->Whatsapp* folder. You can navigate there using a file manager such as [Microsoft's File app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Files/9WZDNCRFJ3PL).

[image: Screenshot - Whatsapp photo save location]

In the above image you can see the folder created by apps such as Zapya, Shareit and Whatsapp. These apps store images in these folder. These folders are located in *SDcard->Pictures*

Answer (score 1):

Photos downloaded from email, I can see mine in Photos -> Downloads (in Photos app). The location of the file is *SDcard->Downloads* .
Usually This is the folder which holds photos downloaded from emails.

[image]

Here you can see Downloads folder, that contains photos downloaded from email.

Comment: There is no such folder in my phone. I use WP8.1. Are you saying about Windows 10 mobile? Cause WP8.1 does not save photos downloaded via Email ***app***. Are you referring to photos downloaded from browser?

Comment: See the attached Picture...

Comment: I could see the picture. But please answer my question. I'm asking this because I could not find such folder although I downloaded an image using Email app. Please indicate ***Whether you used a browser or built in Email app? Are you using Windows 10 mobile?***

Comment: @KolappanNathan I don't exactly remember that it was from browser or email app, but i downloaded photos from email.

Comment: Okay. I tried both. Downloading from a browser saved the photos in **SDcard->Downloads** not Photos->Downloads as you mentioned. Hope you could correct the info. Thanks a lot for your effort

Comment: @KolappanNathan Actually Pictures > Downloads Folder is showing my SDcard > Downloads.

Comment: Are you referring to photos app or File location?

Comment: Photos app actually

Comment: Okay @Nirav Madariya.